# How can I properly say that I've already compensated for a specific day that I didn't work

Tags: word-usage

I have been working with a distributed team for the last 6 months. When I can't work I need to add an event to a shared google calendar that we use. I would like to add in the event's name if I've compensated or not for those hours that I was not available, my question is: is there a word for that? Example:

When I haven't compensated for the hours:

> (In-debt) Dentist

When I've compensated for the hours:

> (Compensated for on the 03/15) Dentist

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by "compensated for", but I suspect that you might be referring to what is often called a [**lieu day**](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/lieu-days.html) or time taken **in lieu** (if it's less than a day).  This is any time off taken in exchange for extra hours worked in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A general business-friendly word that means "not yet completed" is *pending*.

You may consider using the terms *compensation pending* and *compensation completed*.

Comment: I agree with *pending* and *completed*. I might use the term *makeup work* instead of *compensation*.